# bash: sort parts of a file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have some "kind of SQL" files that I want to be partially sorted - to be able to compare them with each other later on.

```
CREATE TABLE BBBBBB
(
   ID bigint NOT NULL
   NAME varchar(50)
   CURRENCY varchar(3)
   SYS_START timestamp NOT NULL
   SYS_END timestamp NOT NULL
   TS_ID timestamp NOT NULL
   EXPORT int
)

CREATE TABLE AA
(
   ID bigint NOT NULL
   SYS_START timestamp NOT NULL
   SYS_END timestamp NOT NULL
   TS_ID timestamp NOT NULL
   NAME varchar(100) NOT NULL
)
```

I only want to have the parts inside the brackets sorted. The output shall be this:

```
CREATE TABLE BBBBBB
(
   CURRENCY varchar(3)
   EXPORT int
   ID bigint NOT NULL
   NAME varchar(50)
   SYS_END timestamp NOT NULL
   SYS_START timestamp NOT NULL
   TS_ID timestamp NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE AA
(
   ID bigint NOT NULL
   NAME varchar(100) NOT NULL
   SYS_END timestamp NOT NULL
   SYS_START timestamp NOT NULL
   TS_ID timestamp NOT NULL
)
```

I tried to put the parts in brackets into the sed hold buffer and sort them, but I didn't get far ... I don't have other ideas right now.

Comment: Do you expect us to write down your program?

Comment: ... Yes. There is always somebody to write down the code for you.

Answer (score 2):

Or `gawk`:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"}
      /^\(/{f=1}
      /^\)/{f=0
            for (i in a)
              print a[i]
            delete a}
      f{a[$1]=$0}
      !f' yourfile
```

Check the *ideone* **demo** [here](http://ideone.com/aTL87U).

From the [**docs**](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Scanning-an-Array)

> **"@ind_str_asc"** Order by indices in ascending order compared as
>   strings; this is the most basic sort. (Internally, array indices are
>   always strings, so with ‘a[2*5] = 1’ the index is "10" rather than
>   numeric 10.)

Comment: strange, on both my aix and linux, sort is done but not like on the OP result. I try different extra action like asort(i) event with array index on first field value but without modification and your code seems correct

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'i {a[l++]=$0}
     /^\(/ {print; i=1}
     /^\)/ {n=asort(a); for(k=1; k<=n; k++){print a[k]} i=0; delete a; next}
     !i' File
```

Comment: though I don't understand a single Piece of this - it works!!

Comment: The logic in short is that, the lines between ( and ) are copied to an array 'a'. When the closing bracket ) is encountered, sort this array and print the contents. Variable i is used to control which all lines gets printed and when ( that's what the !i part does. If i=0, print the line ).

Answer (score 2):

A solution using Vim:

```
vim -c ":/^(/+1,/^)/sort | /^(/-1 | /^(/+1,/^)/sort | wq" x.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -ne '
    $between = /^\(/ .. /^\)/;
    push @buff, $_ if $between && /^\s/;
    print "(\n", sort splice(@buff), ")\n" if $between =~ /E/;
    print unless $between
   ' -- file.sql
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- $between is true if you're between `(` and `)` at the beginning of a line.
- lines starting with whitespace between parentheses are pushed to a buffer.
- the buffer is sorted, printed, and emptied when the last line of the block is read.
- other lines are printed directly.